# Chrome with VLC Web Plugin

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, vlc

Hi I'm working in a project that I need to run a video on Firefox and Chrome, so I install the "VLC Web Plugin" and it is run correctly on Firefox, but I can not install it on Chrome.

I try to install the "ubuntu-extras-restricted" package, install VLC full, install "browser-plugin-vlc" package, but nothing worked for Chrome.

How do install "VLC Web Plugin" for Chrome on Ubuntu?

I read in some places that you can not install "VLC Web Plugin" for Chrome on Ubuntu. It is true?

Configuration:
Chrome: 37.0.2062.120 (Versão oficial 281580)
OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS